# display all results for certain field and one for rest with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to display shops in created area with date for making order. I created a third table to join two that are here already (shops & area) and joined that with inner join. First, I got results like this:

```
area name: name1
shops: shop1
date: date1

area name: name1
shops: shop2
date: date1
```

and I need:

```
area name: name1
shops: shop1, shop2
date: date1
```

then I found some code and included it in script, but it works only for one row (name in code below). If I try with elseif for date with that code it displays wrong. Code is below.

```
<?php
include('db.php'); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area INNER JOIN area_join ON area.id = area_join.area_id INNER JOIN shops ON area_join.shops_id = shops.id ") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());; 
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($data['name'] != $groupname){
echo "<br><hr>Area name: ".$data['name']."<br />Shops: ";
$groupname = $data['name'];
}
echo "".$data['shop_name'].", ";
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`,

```
SELECT  areaName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT shopname) shopList
FROM    area 
        INNER JOIN area_join 
            ON area.id = area_join.area_id 
        INNER JOIN shops 
            ON area_join.shops_id = shops.id 
GROUP   BY  areaName
```

change the *column names* to your original names on found on the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try group_concat? (cant test it now, but i think is this way)

```
SELECT areaname,group_concat(shops) FROM area INNER JOIN area_join ON area.id =    area_join.area_id INNER JOIN shops ON area_join.shops_id = shops.id
Group by areaname
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat